# JavaFX DatePicker hide on mouseExited

Tags: javafx, datepicker, mouseevent

How do i set this kind of behaviour?, currently the hover(mouseEntered) is fine, it shows up the DateChooser whenever the cursor goes inside the DatePicker, but whenever the mouse exits from the DatePicker it hides the DateChooser. I can´t find such method that gives access to the DateChooser itself.

[image]

It´s only fixed to not close the DateChooser when the cursor goes under the DatePicker, but the DateChooser should be close whenever the mouse goes out from it.

```
    datePicker.setOnMouseEntered((event)->{datePicker.requestFocus();datePicker.show();});
    datePicker.setOnMouseExited((event)->{if(event.getY()<23)datePicker.hide();});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the skin allows you to access the content of the popup which allows you access to the popup's `Scene`, which allows you to add a `onMouseExited` handler to that scene for hiding the popup:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> exitHandler = e -> datePicker.hide();
datePicker.setOnShown(evt -> {
    DatePickerSkin skin = (DatePickerSkin) datePicker.getSkin();
    Scene sc = skin.getPopupContent().getScene();
    sc.setOnMouseExited(exitHandler);
});
```

Not a nice solution, since it requires accessing the skin located in the `com.sun` packages, but it is a solution.